# Can I use ether.js with truffle

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethers.js

I have buid a dapp with web3, truffle and metamask, which works perfectly fine.

Now, instead of using a wallet I want to create my own wallet using ether.js, but couldn't figure out a way to use ether.js with truffle.

Is it possible, if yes, how.
Any lead will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Truffle use **Web3** by default and its injected inside as global dependency. You can't get rid of it, but you can **install ether.js** as dependency on your project.

```
truffle init
```

then you install your module

```
npm install --save ethers
```

and eventually you use it in your **truffle tests**

```
var ethers = require('ethers');
```

you can use the **ethers** library into your tests and then execute with `truffle test` command.

Consider that you wouldn't have the library if you use `truffle develop`, since only web3 would be injected.

Comment: I want to get rid of metamask. For that I need something which can do exactly what metamask is doing. Metamask injects web3 into your application but ether js does not do it.  And without metamask's web3 I cant do any transaction. Is there any way I can use etherjs to make transactions from truffle?

Comment: etherjs can be included in your application even if you don't use web3. You still need metamask to connect to the network (as far as I know)

Comment: Is there any way I can make dapp without metamask. If yes, Please share solutions

Comment: No, in order to connect to the network you need a client (metamask, mist browser etc)

Comment: You can use etherjs and abolish metamask completely given you handle the wallet in app. Not advisable for public dapps but if you're working with a private chain it's not a big issue imo.

Comment: You can use the web3 provider that Metamask injects with Ethers.js as well. 
`let provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(web3.eth.currentProvider);`

Answer (score 3):

You can use etheres.js with Truffle, but you might want to consider using frameworks dedicated to ethers.js like [Waffle](https://getwaffle.io)

Waffle is like Truffle, but simpler, faster and sweeter. Also uses ethers.js :)

Answer (score 0):

Ether.js supports several providers, which provide an abstraction to how application code connects to the blockchain; it's well documented [here](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-providers.html).

FWIW, you're also not limited to using truffle as a framework as you can just add ethers to any project via npm/yarn. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

Etherlime is also a framework based on ethers.js and there is a helpful migration guide - https://medium.com/limechain/etherlime-january-status-update-1af29f704b6f