# How to use HardHat behind a proxy

Tags: hardhat

I'm using [HardHat](https://hardhat.org/) ([repo](https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat)) behind a firewall, requiring outbound connections to use a proxy. This is usually pretty easy, for example to [configure NPM](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#proxy) for using proxy, you can set environment variables `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`.

In HardHat, when running commands like `npx hardhat compile`, HardHat reaches out to `https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/windows-amd64/list.json` to get the latest version list of the solidity compiler `solc`. The command fails because it cannot reach out to that address, making the fetch fail and subsequently the command fail. (Error message is below with Stack Trace)

Is there...

A) Configure HardHat to work with a proxy?

or

B) Manually install `solc` (with something like `yarn add solc` and update `hardhat.config.js`) and disable HardHat from checking for a list of compilers and installing a compiler?

Error:

```
HardhatError: HH502: Couldn't download compiler versions list. Please check your connection.
    at CompilerDownloader.downloadCompilersList (C:\Projects\myProject\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\solidity\compiler\downloader.ts:185:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

    Caused by: FetchError: request to https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/windows-amd64/list.json failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
        at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\myProject\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1461:11)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
        at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Edit/Update:

I found the task name [subtask(TASK_COMPILE_SOLIDITY_RUN_SOLCJS)](https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/blob/7b80092c72934da7133a6639ecaf150fc7d0e87d/packages/hardhat-core/src/builtin-tasks/compile.ts#L580)
 to compile using solcjs. Is there a way to configure solcjs as the default compiler? Possibly through an ENV variable?

Update May 2021:

- Link to [issue 1280](https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/issues/1280)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HardHat has added the functionality to set in proxies `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` [the config](https://hardhat.org/guides/compile-contracts.html#configuring-the-compiler) as [@beijingjazzpanda](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/71445/beijingjazzpanda) noted with [PR1291](https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/pull/1291).

> WARNING
>
> Hardhat will automatically download the versions of solc that you set
> up. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, you may need to set the
> HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY environment variable to the URL of your
> proxy.

For some situations where internet access may not be available, consider extending the `hardhat.config.js` as shown in [this example](https://github.com/fvictorio/hardhat-examples/tree/master/custom-solc) to reference a specific `solc` version, similar to the following:

```
const { TASK_COMPILE_SOLIDITY_GET_SOLC_BUILD } = require("hardhat/builtin-tasks/task-names");
const path = require("path");

subtask(TASK_COMPILE_SOLIDITY_GET_SOLC_BUILD, async (args, hre, runSuper) => {
  if (args.solcVersion === "0.8.5") {
    const compilerPath = path.join(__dirname, "soljson-v0.8.5-nightly.2021.5.12+commit.98e2b4e5.js");

    return {
      compilerPath,
      isSolcJs: true, // if you are using a native compiler, set this to false
      version: args.solcVersion,
      // this is used as extra information in the build-info files, but other than
      // that is not important
      longVersion: "0.8.5-nightly.2021.5.12+commit.98e2b4e5"
    }
  }

  // we just use the default subtask if the version is not 0.8.5
  return runSuper();
})

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.5",
};
```

Answer (score 1):

They are trying to resolve this issue.

https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/pull/1291

Comment: Yes. I’ve been waiting on the PR to be merged for a little while. If you’re waiting on this too, please add a comment or “up vote” the issue https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/issues/1280 related to the PR

Comment: Done. Hope this feature can be added soon.

Comment: Agreed. I’ve been waiting since March and cannot wait any longer. I’ll have to use truffle and web3 possibly. Is there a way to use ethers with mocha with truffle?

Comment: You can use ethers.js as an independent package in your truffle project. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50632/can-i-use-ether-js-with-truffle

Comment: You can isolate your project into two projects, one is for Front-end(UI and interacting deployed contract on the chain) and another for developing/compiling/testing/deploying smart contract. It's not big deal using Hardhat or Truffle as long as you can deployed your smart contract to the chain (even can use Remix IDE). Your Front-end program can then use ehters.js to interact with the contract to exchange data and status.

Comment: Compare with Java, Blockchain=server+db, evm=jvm, solidity=java, hardhat/truffle=eclipse, oppenzepellin=spring framework, ethers/web3=RESTful API, ABI=API controller.

Comment: That is what we will be doing. The preference for HardHat and Ethers was more along the lines of style/preference to the surrounding projects. Web3 and Truffle different -- not bad, just different.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue. However, for me hardhat is not able to download list of compiler versions behind corporate proxy. Tried a lot of things. No luck. After a lot of trial and errors, found a way to make this work. Download `list.json`
and keep it locally at `C:\Users\<your-user>\AppData\Local\hardhat-nodejs\Cache\compilers\windows-amd64` (windows). Also, download the solidity compiler executable for windows (required version) from `https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases` and place it in the same folder mentioned above. Now, peruse your `list.json` and identify the object for the solc compiler version of interest. Rename the executable as with the long name given in `path` in that object. For e.g., if you need `solc` version `0.8.0`, the `path` in `list.json` for `0.8.0` version is `solc-windows-amd64-v0.8.4+commit.c7e474f2.exe`. Use this to rename the downloaded executable. Now, run `npm test`. This should fix the issue.

There is also an interesting way to run the compiler within docker on windows. For this, follow the discussion here - https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/1280

Answer (score 0):

adding to above answer, You can also use node_module solc. Please refer to given sample code.

*Files:hardhat.config.ts*

```
import { HardhatUserConfig, subtask } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";
import "hardhat-gas-reporter";

const { TASK_COMPILE_SOLIDITY_GET_SOLC_BUILD } = require("hardhat/builtin-tasks/task-names");
const path = require("path");

subtask(TASK_COMPILE_SOLIDITY_GET_SOLC_BUILD, async (args: any, hre: any, runSuper: any) => {
  if (args.solcVersion === "0.8.17") {
    const compilerPath = path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/solc/soljson.js");

    return {
      compilerPath,
      isSolcJs: true, // if you are using a native compiler, set this to false
      version: args.solcVersion,
      longVersion: "0.8.17",
    };
  }
  return runSuper();
});

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
};

export default config;
```